# combining two return statements into one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

so i have two return statements and i would like to combine them into one Get method. How can i go about doing that properly with what i have:

In my api controller i have:

```
public IEnumerable<GroupUsers> Get(int id)
        {
            return new UserApi().GetUsers(id);
        }
```

and this is my second

```
public int Get()
        {
            var _brand = TenantManager.GetType(Request.RequestUri);
            var _settings = new SettingsService(_brand);
            return _settings.GetValueAsInt(UserSettings, 13);
        }
```

How can i combine them to return both in one method. Also if i wanted to create like a viewModel with the returned results and then return the model in the get method ?

Comment: Create a new class with two properties for both returns, then fill the object of that class and return from your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your ViewModel:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<GroupUsers> GroupUsers { get; set; }
    public int someIntValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now declare a method in your repository to use it:

```
public YourViewModel GetMethodName(int id)
{
  var vm = new YourViewModel();

  var _brand = TenantManager.GetType(Request.RequestUri);
  var _settings = new SettingsService(_brand);

  vm.GroupUsers = UserApi().GetUsers(id);
  vm.someIntValue = _settings.GetValueAsInt(UserSettings, 13);

  return vm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return an item that combines information about several things in a single object, make a class for it:

```
class GroupAndId {
    public IEnumerable<GroupUsers> Users { get; set; }
    public int Id  { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use this class in a `return` statement:

```
return new GroupAndId {
    Users = new UserApi().GetUsers(id);
    Id = _settings.GetValueAsInt(UserSettings, 13);
};
```

Comment: With dynamics, you don't necessarily have to have a pre-defined object, you can just have return new { }. The sub-properties will also be dynamic. Just a bit cleaner if it's only used once.

Comment: what would be my return type if one is IEnumerable and the other is an int?

Comment: @ChrisDixon Combining several things in a single return is often used for data transfer objects as a little trick to save on roundtrips. Using `dynamic` would not work in many frameworks, and it would also hide too much information from the caller.

Comment: @user3244544 The return type would be `GroupAndId` regardless of what's inside it. You would be able to add more members to the class being returned without changing the return type of the function.

Comment: Ahh, apologies, I saw this as a WebAPI method where a single return was viable. On second look, it likely isn't.